# What's this particular 'welcome' screen in Windows 8.1 called? How to disable it?

Tags: windows-8.1

Because [this attempted procedure](https://superuser.com/a/878698) doesn't eliminate [the following especial screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-29-43-metablogapi/2287.Windows_2D00_Update_2D00_message_2D00_shown_2D00_on_2D00_login_2D00_screen_5F00_78A502CE.png), I ought to clarify its name  and question anew.  This screen appears every time whenever I revive my Windows 8.1 PC after hibernation.

[image]

Comment: That is the [lock screen](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-lock-screen-in-windows-8/).

Comment: @Ramhound no, this is the normal login screen. The lockscreen is shown before this normal login screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is the normal login screen that is part of Windows in all Windows NT systems. In the power settings, you can [disable the request of password after resume](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/11685-password-protection-wakeup-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html).

> - Open your Advanced Power Plan Settings:
>
>   - Go to “Control Panel” → “Power Options”.
>   - Find your currently selected power plan,
>       and click/tap on “Change plan settings” link to the right of that plan.
>   - Click/tap on the “Change advanced power settings” link.
>
>   and click tap on the “Change settings that are currently unavailable” link.
> - If prompted by UAC, click/tap on “Yes”.
> - Change the “Require a password on wakeup” setting(s) to “No”, and click/tap on “OK”.